# Basic Authentication won't work using MAMP

Tags: php, mysql, mamp, basic-authentication

I am reading the book PHP and MySQL: The Missing Manual 2nd Edition and I am at the point where I need to use Basic Authentication in order to access certain web pages.

When I try to navigate to a restricted page, I should be prompted to enter a username and password to continue to the page, however I am not receiving the prompt to do so.  I have added the PHP headers:

```
header('HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized');
header('WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="The Social Site"');
```

to my script and, to my knowledge, this should present the prompt box to me in order to continue to the page, but it does not do so.  I have been trying to get this to work for about two hours now and I haven't been able to find anything on the internet that helps.

Does anyone know why this is not working for me?  Any help is appreciated!

NOTE:  I have been using MAMP to complete all examples in the book and I haven't had any major problems like this up until this point.

Comment: This code works for me on a web-hosted server. Must be a MAMP issue.

Comment: This only occurs when you are using CGI mode for PHP in MAMP. I haven't found an easy and fast solution to that problem yet, so I decided to change the PHP mode (to PHP as a module) to fix it temporarily.